# Assistance needed with the new Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code and I have linked to jQuery etc. However when I click to move the carousel it does the same thing as:

```
<a href="#"></a>
```

does.

Can anyone help me fix my code! Thanks in advance!

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="img/slide1.jpg" alt="" width="100%" height="50%">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Test1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="img/slide1.jpg" alt="" width="100%" height="50%">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Test2
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next"></span>
  </a>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">





</div>


<script type="text/javascript">$('.carousel').carousel()</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the script tag for the carousel after initialising the jQuery library.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">$('.carousel').carousel()</script>
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if your JavaScript is being loaded?

Comment: How would I do that? Sorry, I am a noob at this XD!

Comment: Hey never mind I looked it up, that was the issue, many thanks man!